# TypeError: $http.get is not a function in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use Angular Service and since $scope can not be injected inside service so using $rootScope. My code look like fine but getting following error-

### TypeError: $http.get is not a function

Here is code-
EmployeeService.js:
///

```
app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var employees = [];
    return {
        fetchEmp: function () {
            debugger;
            return $http.get("EmpWebService.asmx/GetEmp")
                .then(function (response) {
                    employees = response.data;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('allEmployees', employees);
                    return employees;
                });
        }

    };
}]);
```

In my controller I am trying to consume it like below:

```
$scope.employees = fetchEmpService.fetchEmp();
$scope.$on('allEmployees', function (events, employees) {
        $scope.employees = employees;
    });
```

I am bit confuse that will the data will come inside  $scope.$on

Comment: You have your parameters in the wrong order.  `$rootScope` is injected first.  Swap them around and it should be fine

Comment: Change the answer in this line `app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($http, $rootScope)`. Here the injecting order is important. `app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your parameters and array of injectables are in a different order.

This:

```
app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($http, $rootScope)
```

Needs to be

```
app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http)
```

The order is important and needs to be the same.

More information on [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: Correct, I this was the reason. Thank You

Comment: @RiteshGupta No problem. Remember, if this is the correct answer, mark it as correct so others can see it in the future.

Comment: Ok,Marked it as correct answer. But my second issue is still open,is that what is role of this line
  $rootScope.$broadcast('allEmployees', employees);
I commented and code still works fine.

Comment: @RiteshGupta That is a separate question, so you should make another post. Before you do though, take a  look at [Angular scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). Especially the section on `$broadcast` and `$on`.